# Import sas data into hadoop

Tags: hadoop, sas

We are buying third party survey data. They are providing us data in SAS format.

Source data format - SAS
Frequency - Daily
Data - Full one year data set (no delta)

We would like to bring this data into our Hadoop environment on daily basis. What are our options.

We asked them to send the data in text file. But their text file had 8650 columns (for ex. Country .. so they had 250 columns - one with each country). Our ETL tool failed to process that many columns. According to them it is mush easier to read data in SAS format.

Any suggestion..

Thx

Comment: What ETL tool are you using? How is that tied to Hadoop? Does it have a HDFS connector? Can you provide a sample of SAS format which you are getting?

Comment: I would like to know if SAS data can be imported to Hadoop on regular basis. If yes, what are the tools ? What steps do I need to follow at the high level. So I can create good Business case.
Datastage was the ETL tool but that time data was going to DB2.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is not a technology problem... It sounds like they are just being unhelpful. I do most of my work in SAS and would never provide someone with a table with that many columns and expect them to import it.

Even if they sent it in SAS format, the SAS dataset is still going to have the same number of columns and the ETL tool (even if it could read in SAS datasets - which is unlikely) is still likely to fail.

Tell them to transpose the data in SAS so that there are fewer columns and then to re-send it as a text file.

Comment: Appreciate your response. Currently, we receive three files for each survey:
1. Contents 
2. Format

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone..

I think, this would solve my issue:

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/modules/tolong.htm